# Give div a style when redirecting with header

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am redirecting to a page with a header link `header('Location: ../index.php?resp=resp2#contact');` and when I press that link I want my div to start with the style `left: 12vw`. I don't want this to happen when you refresh the page. How can I do this?

I tried stuff with a `resp` in the link, but I already make use of `resp`'s and I don't think it's possible to send 2 `resp`'s at once? I also tried doing it with javascript so when a page is reloaded it will give the style, but then it also triggers on refresh.

It doesn't matter if it is javascript, JQuery , php or just normal html/css, I just hope I'll get it to work.

Comment: Alright I'll try to get that to work.

Comment: @FirstOne post this as an answer. It's pretty much what I was about the suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a session variable before the redirection, if the variable is set, echo that style and clear the given variable. That way, on refresh, it will not echo the style.

Page with redirection:

```
// session_start(); // if not yet started
$_SESSION['style_div'] = true;
header('Location: ../index.php?resp=resp2#contact');
exit; // just in case;
```

Page with given DIV:

```
// ... [probably some code]
// session_start(); // if not yet started
if(isset($_SESSION['style_div'])){
    unset($_SESSION['style_div']);
    echo '<div style="left: 12vw ...">';
}else{
    echo '<div style="...">';
};
// ... [rest of code]
```

Comment: Oh it worked but 1 part of my JQuery code stopped this, `$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
            aroundcfside.style.right = "calc(100vw - 120px)";
            arrowcf.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
        }).scroll()` so when it refreshes it first opens it and then goes to the page jump so it notifies scrolling. Do you maybe know a fix for this?

Comment: Anyways it did answer this question and if you don't know how to fix this part I'll answer it in a later question. I think it has to do with php loading before everything (like JQuery)